# How to get updated data after refreshing a webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload, browser-cache, partial-page-refresh

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC3. I have a `table` where table data contains textbox where user has to enter a value and submit. I'm using a jQuery AJAX call for submitting the data to back end. On success function I'm using `location.reload(true);` still after refreshing the page it shows cached value. However i've set `cache: false`

The following is my jQuery ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/SubmitData",
    data: values: h,
    cache:false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data has been submitted successfully');
        location.reload(true);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server side code is updating your database correctly?

Comment: yes Updation is working fine..

Comment: Don't you have a cache at repository level (nhibernate, entity framework ?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your $.ajax call functions properly? What is that for a kind of data you are submitting: 'values : h'?
I just mean you could send data as JSON. But your syntax is wrong. You have to form an object, eg:

```
{ 'values' : h }
```

Thats just an example if in your case 'h' contains more values (array)  you should formerly express them as JSON, too. There are Javascript functions that transform array to JSON- objects for you.

So test your $.ajax call and prove your web console if any error are shown. Also use

```
console.log("....");
```

and also

```
console.dir(obj);
```

to show an object tree.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: +1 @BhushanKawadkar considering that there is very little info and that many things could be going wrong, I think this answer is a good start. It is pointing out syntax errors which if corrected could possibly be the fix to the problem. So, why do you think providing information and highlight coding issues is not an answer?